# How can I reference data from an already existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have connected my app to a MS SQL database, but I wanted to know how I can start referencing the data that was already in the database (but in another table). Do I have to generate anything in my app / resources etc.?

Comment: You need to setup `ActiveRecord` models. Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As Dharam said, you need to genereate Active Record model. Rails using MVC architecture, if you need to learn first about MVC, go to [Rails getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

If you already have table, with data and structure, you don't need to generate it, you can generate ActiveRecord model without migration with this command.

```
rails g model ModelName --migration=false
```